# Proving $\sqrt{6}$ is irrational

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

Assume it is rational. So $6 = \frac{p^2}{q^2}$ and $(p,q)=1$. So $p^2 = 6q^2 = 2 (3q^2)$. So $p^2$ is even and so $p$ is even. Let $p=2r$. So $p^2 = 4r^2$. Putting back in the equation, I get $2r^2=3q^2$. So $3 \cdot q \cdot q$ is divisible by $2$. So $q^2$ is divisible by $2$ and so $q$ is even and it divisible by $2$. So $2$ is a common divisor of $p$ and $q$ which is a contradiction.

Is this correct? I could also have proved that $3$ is common factor of $p$ and $q$.  Will that be correct too? Thanks.

Comment: yes it seems legit

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: Yes to both questions. (However, you implicitly assumed $p,q\neq 0$, which you was correct.)

Comment: What does $(p,q)=1$ denote?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo it means Greatest common fivisor of a and b is 1. Is it not standard notation ?

Comment: So i have to prove that square root of 4 is irrational by imitating the proof of 
Let $ \sqrt4 = \frac{p}{q} $ . So $4q^2=p^2$. So $p^2=2(2q^2)$. So $2$ divides $p$. Let $p=2r, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Put in equation i get $q^2=r^2$. So $q = \pm r$. If r is even, then q is even and also p is even. So i get a contradiction. 

Where is the erroe ?

Thanks

Comment: Wait, the square root of $4$ is rational! $\sqrt 4 = \pm 2$.

Comment: $r$ is odd as is $q$, since $(q, r) =1$ and $q=\pm r$ that implies that $q=r=1$.

Comment: @kingW3 how did (q,r)=1 happen to be ?

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook Comes from $(q,p)=1$ then $(q,2r)=1$ which implies $(q,r)=1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could have done it with any prime (that divides $6$ exactly). Specifically, what you are using is the fact that prime numbers are exactly the natural numbers $p\ge2$ such that for all $a,b$ such that $p\mid ab$, either $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$.

Comment: I did not get what you are saying about p |ab

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook $m\mid n$ is notation of "$m$ divides $n$".

Comment: You mean to say it works for only prim. bUT every number can be written as product of primes

Comment: saY if i try to prove $\sqrt4$ is irrational.

Comment: There is no prime that divides $4$ exactly.

Comment: So i have to prove that square root of 4 is irrational by imitating the proof of 
Let $ \sqrt4 = \frac{p}{q} $ . So $4q^2=p^2$. So $p^2=2(2q^2)$. So $2$ divides $p$. Let $p=2r, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Put in equation i get $q^2=r^2$. So $q = \pm r$. If r is even, then q is even and also p is even. So i get a contradiction. 

Where is the erroe ?

Thanks

Comment: "So I get a contradiction". No: "So I get $r$ is odd".

Comment: Well,  r can be even too

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook It can't because you get a contradiction if r is even as you said.

Answer (score 0):

The general proof that any $x^n = \sum_{p=0}^{n-1} a_p x^p$, then if x is not in Z, then x is irrational, is to note that the span of powers of x is closed to multiplication, and that there exists no set of fractions so closed, therefore x is either integer or irrational.

The value $x=\sqrt{6}$ becomes $x^2=6$, is of this form, and since $x$ is not an integer, it must be irrational.

Comment: So i have to prove that square root of 4 is irrational by imitating the proof of 
Let $ \sqrt4 = \frac{p}{q} $ . So $4q^2=p^2$. So $p^2=2(2q^2)$. So $2$ divides $p$. Let $p=2r, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Put in equation i get $q^2=r^2$. So $q = \pm r$. If r is even, then q is even and also p is even. So i get a contradiction. 

Where is the erroe ?

Thanks

Comment: The solution to the equations of the type of my answer, are 'algebraic integers'.  The intersection of algebraic integers and rational numbers, are the integers.  Here we have $\sqrt{4} = 2$, is an integer.  There is no contriduction.  In your example, if $4q^2=p^2$, then $p$ is even, even where $q$ isn't.  But the solution does not imply any condition except $p=\pm 2q$ since it equates to $(\pm 2)^2 = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Seems OK. Let me supplement:

Show :

If $2|p^2$ then $2|p$.

Euclid's lemma:

If a prime $r$ divides $ab$ then $r$ divides $a$ or $r$ divides $b.$

In your case:

$2|p^2$, i.e. $2|pp$,

implies  $2|p$.

Comment: So i have to prove that square root of 4 is irrational by imitating the proof of 
Let $ \sqrt4 = \frac{p}{q} $ . So $4q^2=p^2$. So $p^2=2(2q^2)$. So $2$ divides $p$. Let $p=2r, r \in \mathbb{Z}$. Put in equation i get $q^2=r^2$. So $q = \pm r$. If r is even, then q is even and also p is even. So i get a contradiction. 

Where is the erroe ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to show that√4=2 is irrational?

Comment: yes, to check if same proof works

Comment: @ReadThyOwnBook you don't get any contradiction. You get that r  is not even, so it is odd. Since p and q don't have any common factors, so neither have r and q (and q=r or q=-r), it means that q=1 or -1 and r=1 or -1. (and p=2 or -2). Congrats, you found that the square roots of 4 are 2 and -2.